# How can I extract the line which exists 2 lines before the matching line?

Tags: parsing, text, sed, awk, grep

I have a big unix text file and I want to get the line that exists 3 lines above the matching line.

How can I do that?

Note I do not want to get the lines in between. Hence, if text is

```
one
two
three
four
```

and I am looking for string 'three', I want to get as output

```
one
```

and not

```
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one: first grep the word you're looking for with context two lines back:

```
$ grep -B 2
```

which gives:

```
one
two
three
--
one
two
three
--
one
two
three
(...)
```

then print every fourth line using sed:

```
$ grep -B 2 three test.txt |sed -n '1~4'p
```

(got the sed part from here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-printing-file-lines-using-address-and-patterns/

Answer (score 1):

Using awk
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Basics.html#Array-Basics

```
awk -v n=3 '{s[NR%n]=$0} /three/{print s[(NR-n+1)%n]}' foo.txt
```

Comment: `s[(NR-n+1)]` could be simplified as `s[(NR+1)%n]`. To be on the safe side, you could replace `/three/` by `NR >= n && /three/` to ensure that we have already seen n lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep  with below options

```
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.


   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.
```

Hence as per your requirement, use the command:

```
grep -B 3 three <filename>
```

Comment: No. `grep -B` is not an option, because it prints the lines in between. See my note on the question. It clearly says that I do not want the lines in between.